# In Disjoint Set Union (D.S.U.), why do we make the smaller sized subset as the child of the larger sized subset while performing the union operation?

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search, disjoint-sets, disjoint-union

I recently came across D.S.U. and its applications on the tree.As i was solving the related problems, I got Time Limit Exceeded error in some so i read the tutorial again and there I found that an improvised version of the normal union is weighted-union. In this weighted union operation, we make the smaller sized subset's root as child of larger sized  subset's(among the two) root. How is it benefiting us?
Link to [Tutorial](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/disjoint-data-strutures/basics-of-disjoint-data-structures/tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't make difference in correctness' point of view, but it is usually faster.

Check this example:

[image]

In the first case, you put the biggest set as child of the smallest. You can see that in this case, if you try the **find** method in the deepest node, it will perform 3 steps. This doesn't happen in the second case.

This is not a rule but pratically it's what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You should realise the purpose/logic behind weighted union-find.

First, why do we need weighted union-find? That's because a simple inefficient union-find can lead to an unbalanced tree. In the worst cast a linked list. What's the complexity of traversal over a linked list? `O(N)`. That's the worst complexity when using a simple union-find.

Our goal is - balancing the hence-formed tree.

How and why weighted union-find works? It's a simple optimization by just keeping the size of each subset and making the smaller subset child of the larger subset when performing union between the two.

**Why this works?** Because, as mentioned, our goal is to balance out the tree when doing the union and not unbalance it. If you make the smaller subset a child of the larger subset, the height of the overall tree is not increasing (obv when the sizes are equal we handle it differently :/). On the other hand, if you make the bigger subset a child of the smaller tree, you know what will happen.

Using just this optimization we improve the worst case time complexity from `O(N)` to `O(log2(N))` - because the height of the tree will never go beyond `log2(N)`

There's another optimization that can be done along with this which will take the complexity down even further. Your link probably has it.